# Button elements only works when I tap on trackbar instead of click. I want to make the elements to be able to react on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

The click only seems to work when I include display into inventoryChecker(), but itemAmt of the element doesn't change.

```
let nameList = []
let itemAmt = []
let itemDesc = []
let itemRar = []
let display = []

function inventoryChecker() {
  let FW = formatWhole

  for (var z = 0; z < nameList.length; z++) {
    if (itemAmt[z] !== 0) {
      display.push(`<button name="${nameList[z]}" class="item ${itemRar[z]}" onClick="useItem(${z})" title="${itemDesc[z]}">${nameList[z]}<span style="float:right"><small>x${FW(itemAmt[z])}</small></span></button><br>`)
    } else {
      display.splice(z, 1)
    }
  }

  display = display.sort().join("")

  $("inventory").innerHTML = display
}
```

Is there any way I can make it react on a click instead of a tap?

When I declared display by itself, the click would register, but the itemAmt won't decrease at all.

Comment: What's the difference between tap and click? On a touch display, you click on something by tapping on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "include display into inventoryChecker()".

Comment: BTW, having lots of parallel arrays like this is generally poor design. Use an array of objects to keep all the related information together.

Comment: What's the purpose of `display.splice(z, 1)`? You haven't pushed anything into element `z` of the array yet, so there's nothing to remove.

Comment: I apologize for the mess for this is my first time making an inventory system myself.

Comment: You still need to clarify the explanation of the problem.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.